# Canopy - get Access Denied error

Tags: python, canopy

I'm learning python (from a very low baseline) and recently re-installed Canopy (on a MacBook) It was working fine before.

Now whenever I try an launch the editor I get a Access Denied error.

Can anyone help? Please bear in mind my inexperience

Thanks

File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/envisage/ui/tasks/tasks_application.py", line 205, in create_window
    window.add_task(task)
  File "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyface/tasks/task_window.py", line 187, in add_task
    state.dock_panes.append(dock_pane_factory(task=task))
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/canopy/plugin/editor_task.py", line 143, in _create_python_pane
  File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/envisage/application.py", line 371, in get_service
    protocol, query, minimize, maximize
  File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/envisage/service_registry.py", line 78, in get_service
    services = self.get_services(protocol, query, minimize, maximize)
  File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/envisage/service_registry.py", line 115, in get_services
    actual_protocol, name, obj, properties, service_id
  File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/envisage/service_registry.py", line 259, in _resolve_factory
    obj = obj(**properties)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/canopy/python_frontend/plugin.py", line 109, in _frontend_manager_service_factory
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/canopy/app/running_process_manager.py", line 82, in register_proc
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/canopy/app/util.py", line 53, in get_exe_or_cmdline
  File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_common.py", line 80, in **get**
    ret = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/**init**.py", line 331, in exe
    return guess_it(fallback=err)
  File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/**init**.py", line 314, in guess_it
    cmdline = self.cmdline
  File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/**init**.py", line 346, in cmdline
    return self._platform_impl.get_process_cmdline()
  File "/Users/simonthompson/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psutil/_psosx.py", line 153, in wrapper
    raise AccessDenied(self.pid, self._process_name)
AccessDenied: (pid=343)
DEBUG|2013-11-03 21:19:25|QtWarningMsg: QImage::scaled: Image is a null image

Comment: you should give more detail, perhaps a screenshot.
It seems to be user authentication problem on your macbook.

Comment: Couldn't add the whole log file so have added the last part. No idea if that helps really. Apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the supplied information is insufficient, the answer is the same. This is about user authentication. I don't know how you open the app but, your app tries to open a file or a process which is could not be opened by your user. If you open your app with root privileges there won't be any problem.